# I using Pdf-node-creator for generating pdf in my node application, It was working fine in local environment , But in production I get the below Error

Tags: pdf, html-pdf

I dono why I am getting this error please help

Error message

[Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\tmp\html-pdf-6364.pdf'] {
errno: -4058,
code: 'ENOENT',
syscall: 'open',
path: 'C:\tmp\html-pdf-6364.pdf'
}

Comment: The error is telling you that the path 'C:\tmp\html-pdf-6364.pdf' that you're using as argument of 'open' does not exist, or cannot be resolved. That's as much as we can help you I suppose

Comment: But I am not using or provided that path in any of my code !, Actually I got an reference that html-pdf uses C:/tmp folder for storing buffer but in virtual machines we cannot use the folder not without root password so we cannot use buffer in node server. Thank you any other answers are welcome